# Port code to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I found some code online. It is in C# and I am trying to port it to vb.net. I need some help with calling the evaluator function from within the Log subroutine. In C#, evaluator does not appear to expect any parameters when it gets called in Log. However, VB keeps asking for the Match parameter. What is the magic and how should I get it to work in VB.NET? Thanks.

```
private string evaluator(Match match)
{
    Pri pri = new Pri(match.Groups[1].Value);
    return pri.ToString()+" ";
}

private void Log(EndPoint endPoint, string strReceived)
{
...
string strMessage = string.Format("{0} : {1}", 
    endPoint, m_regex.Replace(strReceived, evaluator));
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# version is using the `(string, MatchEvaluator)` overload of `Regex.Replace()`, and using the implicit conversion of the method name to the `MatchEvaluator` delegate type. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) on that overload.

On the MSDN page, this is how they call it:

```
Dim result As String = rx.Replace(text, AddressOf RegExSample.CapText)
```

So make sure to use the `AddressOf` keyword.